# JVM crash.. How to get err log or core dump

Tags: java, jvm, jna, coredump, jvm-crash

I have a java application that calls a native dll using jna. The program crashes JVM in the middle after my callback in java is execute and throw "java platform se binary has stopped" dialogue box. the java console logs are not useful, there is nothing there. How to get a core dump or some other useful logs in the windows for figuring out the issue and where it is causing it. looked for hs_err log in the temp folder but could not find it.

Answer (score 1):

We have been seeing this error since past few days with JVM (openjdk 8) running on our RHEL platforms. we notice it generate some error message in /var/log/message file which writes about the location of core_dump file as below.

2020-01-29T03:08:14.980998+00:00 lon6pvlpdgrd103 abrt[2274]: Saved core dump of pid 40132 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222.b10-0.el6_10.x86_64/jre/bin/java) to /var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2020-01-29-03:08:10-40132 (1048576000 bytes)

I think its OS level feature to generate core-dump when process crashes abnormally.
This page help further in knowing the reason for crash: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/crashes001.html
For windows please refer to section 17.4.4 Collect Crash Dumps on Windows form above article.
Please check if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The hs_err file is usually written in the "current directory" for the JVM process.  If the directory is not writable by the user then the file is written to a temporary directory.  You can also tell the JVM to write the fatal error report to a specified file.

A core dump will only be written if the "core file size" ulimit (or equivalent) is large enough and their is enough file space.  The default ulimit is zero.

For more information:

- [Location of Fatal Error Log](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/felog001.html)
- [Collect Core Dumps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/bugreports004.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use `-XX:ErrorFile` to specify the error file.

From [Location of Fatal Error Log](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/felog001.html):

> To specify where the log file will be created, use the product flag -XX:ErrorFile=file, where file represents the full path for the log file location.

Also, this:

> If the -XX:ErrorFile=file flag is not specified, the default log file name is hs_err_pid.log, where pid is the PID of the process.